# How would you solve this sequence for convergence or diveregence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

The question provides the $n$th term which is
$$a_n=\frac{\sin(5n)}{1+\sqrt{n}}$$
and the question doesn't say but I assume its $n\rightarrow\infty$ as it's asking for convergence or divergence.

What I got so far is that since the numerator will always be between $-1$ and $1$ and that the denominator will become positive infinity as $n\rightarrow\infty$ the sequence will converge to $0$.

I am not sure if I am right, and I do not know any other way to solve this question so anything helps thanks.

Comment: Please format your math using MathJax. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1):

You can formalize your intuition using the "squeeze theorem". If for large enough $n$ you have that $a_n \leq u_n \leq b_n$ and $\lim a_n  = \lim b_n = \ell$, you can conclude that $u_n$ converges and that $\lim u_n = \ell$. In this case, since
$$
\dfrac{-1}{1+\sqrt{n}}\leq \dfrac{\sin 5n}{1+\sqrt{n}}\leq \dfrac{1}{1+\sqrt{n}}
$$

and

$$
\lim \dfrac{-1}{1+\sqrt{n}} = \lim \dfrac{1}{1+\sqrt{n}} = 0,
$$

your conclusion is correct: the sequence converges and the limit is zero.